# "I can do it no problem" vs "I can do it, no problem"

Tags: commas

Is it wrong to write, "I can do it no problem" vs "I can do it, no problem"?

I was writing an email today and wrote, "Now we can meet our deadline no problem", and came to think of this question. The way I would say this makes me want to omit the comma when writing it out.

Comment: Now we can meet our deadline without difficulty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, "no problem" is considered informal by most dictionaries, such as [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/no%20problem), so you maybe shouldn't use it at all in formal communications, and some of the examples I discuss might be considered non-standard or ungrammatical by prescriptivists, despite being widely used, so do at your own risk.

Informally either of your variations is possible, although using a comma could change the meaning. In summary, "I can do it no problem" means "I can do it easily", while "I can do it, no problem" more likely means "I can do it, and I'm fine with you asking."

In informal contexts, "No problem" is normally used on its own as an interjection (example: see [Collins Cobuild](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/no-problem). This is found in most dictionaries, and they say it means that you don't mind doing what you've been asked to do. Examples are "Could you help me carry this?" "No problem!" Here you'd normally have it punctuated as a separate sentence, although informally it is possible to join it with either something like a semicolon, or a comma splice: "I can do it, no problem."="I can do it. No problem." [Comma splices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_splice) (Wikipedia) are frowned upon by some people but are common in casual writing: to avoid them, you could use a period instead and have "no problem" as a separate sentence. So if you have a comma before "no problem" it might suggest you are saying "I've no objection to doing this".

However in casual writing there are many examples of "no problem" being used as an adverbial expression meaning "easily" or "without any problems". This sense isn't in the dictionaries I checked (Wiktionary, Collins, Merriam-Webster), but you can find examples in the wild. For instance [a correspondent to the Guardian](https://www.theguardian.com/notesandqueries/query/0,5753,-58770,00.html) (undated but early 21st century) writes "I could do it no problem having seen it on a map and having done that trip before" And from [Elon Musk on Twitter in 2019](https://twitter.com/elonmusk/status/1115340229005561857), replying to "Will it require going to a service center or can it be done by mobile?" answered "Mobile can do it no problem". In this usage a comma is not included in the examples because the speaker considers it important information, but it could be used if it was considered an add-on or not central to the sentence (meanings similar to "I could do it and it's easy").